# Angular Reactive Validation

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-material, angular-directive

I am new to angular, I want to know how the reactive validation works in angular 6.0, I am trying to do the validation from last 2 weeks, can someone help me to do the validation? and teach me how to do it.

your help is highly appreciated, Thank you :)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators  } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'AngularProject';

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) 
  {}
  profileForm : FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.profileForm= this.fb.group({
          firstName:['', [Validators.required]],
          EmailMe:['',[Validators.required]]
        });
  }

  onSubmit():void
  {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.profileForm.invalid) {
      return;
  }
    console.log(this.profileForm.value);
    alert('SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n' + JSON.stringify(this.profileForm.value))
  }
  get f() { 
    return  this.profileForm.controls; 
}}
```

The HTML part is given below.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">

    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">C3</h3>
    </div>


  <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="fullName">Full Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input id="fullName" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName"
          [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.profileForm.errors }" >

          <div *ngIf="f.firstName.errors.required">First Name is required {{f.profileForm.errors}}</div>
          <div *ngIf=></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="EmailMe">
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!profileForm.valid">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
 <!--  -->

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#reactive-form-validation

Comment: Hi @AJT_82, can you suggest me any good book on angular ?

Comment: I would recommend the official angular tutorials, you can start with the tour of heroes, it covers most essential things. Good thing about the official tutorial is that they are also always up to date :)

Comment: Thank you AJT_82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validation check seems to be wrong. Here, give this a try:

```
<form 
  class="form-horizontal" 
  [formGroup]="profileForm" 
  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  <div class="panel panel-primary">

    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">C3</h3>
    </div>


    <div class="panel-body">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label 
          class="col-sm-2 control-label" 
          for="fullName">
          Full Name
        </label>

        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input 
            id="fullName" 
            type="text" 
            class="form-control" 
            formControlName="firstName">
          <div 
            *ngIf="profileForm.controls['firstName'].touched && profileForm.controls['firstName'].errors.required"
            >
            First Name is required
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      ...

    </div>

    ...

  </div>

</form>
```

---

Also Angular automatically applies classes like ng-invalid and ng-touched on invalid and touched form controls. So you can leverage that to simplify your CSS:

```
input.ng-touched.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-validation-eg?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Thank you for the example, it helped me alot, thank you

Comment: if you get rid of any text it should show you the validation error as well as for email, if both are validated, the button needs to be enabled

Comment: Hi SiddAjmera, is this the reactive form validation?

Comment: Yeah, I guess. If it's applied on a Reactive Form, that makes it reactive form validation. What makes you think otherwise? What's the definition of Reactive Form Validation btw? I'm not sure. It can be relative. So just asking to be sure.

Comment: I'm not sure, I am new to angular, my background is .net :(

Comment: Well. Yes. Since you're using the Reactive Forms approach for building forms, the validation that you've applied on them are also reactive in nature. The state of the form controls will change(react) to changes in the control's value. Does that make sense now?

Comment: yes it does, can you provide me any crash course for angular ? I am trying really hard to learn

Comment: Thank you, I will buy that this week

Answer (score 0):

in several places in template you access

```
f.proflieForm
```

but f is defined as

```
get f() { return this.profileForm.controls; }
```

the controls on profileForm have no control also called profileForm, you probably want more like:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="fullName">Full Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input id="fullName" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName"
      [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.firstName.errors }" >

      <div *ngIf="f.firstName.errors?.required">First Name is required {{f.firstName.errors}}</div>
      <div *ngIf=></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

everything else looks like it should work fine, but you haven't added any error fields to your email form, though you mark it as required in it's form control.

Comment: Thank you, I cannot give you up vote because I have only 1 reputation, but it worked